# How to use Razor Section multiple times in a View & PartialView (merge) without overriding it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In the _Layout.cshtml file, I have a section at the bottom of the body called "ScriptsContent" declared like this:

```
@RenderSection("ScriptsContent", required: false)
```

In my view, I can then use this section to add scripts to be executed. But what if I also have a PartialView that also need to use this section to add additional scripts?

**View**

```
@section ScriptsContent
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert(1);
    </script>
}

@Html.Partial("PartialView")
```

**PartialView**

```
@section ScriptsContent
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert(2);
    </script>
}
```

**Result**

Only the first script is rendered. The second script doesn't exist in source code of the webpage.

Razor seems to only output the first *@section ScriptsContent* that it sees. What I would like to know is if there's a way to merge each call to the section.

If we cannot do this, what do you propose?

Comment: Can you post the ScriptsContent or its pattern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution for that problem. It's from this blog: http://blog.logrythmik.com/post/A-Script-Block-Templated-Delegate-for-Inline-Scripts-in-Razor-Partials.aspx

```
public static class ViewPageExtensions
{        
    private const string SCRIPTBLOCK_BUILDER = "ScriptBlockBuilder";

    public static MvcHtmlString ScriptBlock(this WebViewPage webPage, Func<dynamic, HelperResult> template)
    {
        if (!webPage.IsAjax)
        {
            var scriptBuilder = webPage.Context.Items[SCRIPTBLOCK_BUILDER] as StringBuilder ?? new StringBuilder();

            scriptBuilder.Append(template(null).ToHtmlString());
            webPage.Context.Items[SCRIPTBLOCK_BUILDER] = scriptBuilder;

            return new MvcHtmlString(string.Empty);
        }

        return new MvcHtmlString(template(null).ToHtmlString());
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString WriteScriptBlocks(this WebViewPage webPage)
    {
        var scriptBuilder = webPage.Context.Items[SCRIPTBLOCK_BUILDER] as StringBuilder ?? new StringBuilder();

        return new MvcHtmlString(scriptBuilder.ToString());
    }
}
```

so anywwhere in your View or PartialView you can use this:

```
@this.ScriptBlock(
    @<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert(1);
    </script>
)
```

and in your _Layout or MasterView, use this:

```
@this.WriteScriptBlocks()
```

Comment: I would not recommend this approach because you will get into trouble the first time you use the ``OutputCache`` attribute on a controller action. Because nothing is rendered in your partial view explicitly, the script blocks won't be rendered twice if the first request was cached. See also the comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15363037/1823162

Comment: I didnt had this problem yet and i use this script on many projects here. But honestly, we havent used the OutputCache intensivly yet so maybe i will have this problem someday. For now, it do the job for us but i will keep an eye on this problem. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: I solved this by storing in a static concurrent dictionary. The key must be unique for the RawUrl.

Comment: @nfplee, can you post your code? or maybe update my answer if the base idea is the same?

Comment: @AlexandreJobin: I've added an answer with my fix. It may require a little work your end if you're not using Donut Output Caching  but it was pretty simple to do. I've even managed to improve it so that it is not reliant on the RawUrl and should work for whatever your cache varies on. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to share sections between a view and partial views.

Absent a ScriptManager-like solution, you could have a collection of script files (initialized in your view and stored either in `HttpContext.Items` or in `ViewData`) to which the partial view would append the script file names it requires. Then towards the end of your view you would declare a section that fetches that collection and emits the right script tags.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the accepted answer is that it breaks Output Caching. The trick to solving this is to overwrite the OutputCache attribute with your own implementation. Unfortunately we can't extend the original attribute since it has lots of internal methods which we need to access.

I actually use Donut Output Caching which overwrites the OutputCache attribute itself. There are alternative libraries which also use their own OutputCache attribute so I will explain the steps I made to get it to work so that you can apply it to whichever one you're using.

First you need to copy the existing OutputCache attribute and place it within your application. You can get the existing attribute by looking at the source code.

Now add the following property to the class. This is where we store the script blocks so we can render the correct ones when retrieving from the cache.

```
public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, StringBuilder> ScriptBlocks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, StringBuilder>();
```

Now inside the OnActionExecuting method you need to store the cache key (the unique identifier for the output cache) inside the current requests collection. For example:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Items["OutputCacheKey"] = cacheKey;
```

Now modify the ViewPageExtensions class by adding the following (replacing CustomOutputCacheAttribute with the name of your attribute):

```
var outputCacheKey = webPage.Context.Items["OutputCacheKey"] as string;

if (outputCacheKey != null)
    CustomOutputCacheAttribute.ScriptBlocks.AddOrUpdate(outputCacheKey, new StringBuilder(template(null).ToHtmlString()), (k, sb) => {
        sb.Append(template(null).ToHtmlString());

        return sb;
    });
```

before:

```
return new MvcHtmlString(string.Empty);
```

Note: For a slight performance boost you'll also want to make sure you only call "template(null).ToHtmlString()" once.

Now return to your custom OutputCache attribute and add the following **only when you are retrieving from the cache** inside the OnActionExecuting method:

```
if (ScriptBlocks.ContainsKey(cacheKey)) {
    var scriptBuilder = filterContext.HttpContext.Items["ScriptBlockBuilder"] as StringBuilder ?? new StringBuilder();

    scriptBuilder.Append(ScriptBlocks[cacheKey].ToString());

    filterContext.HttpContext.Items["ScriptBlockBuilder"] = scriptBuilder;
}
```

Here's the final code of my attribute:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI;
using DevTrends.MvcDonutCaching;

public class CustomOutputCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter {
    private readonly IKeyGenerator _keyGenerator;
    private readonly IDonutHoleFiller _donutHoleFiller;
    private readonly IExtendedOutputCacheManager _outputCacheManager;
    private readonly ICacheSettingsManager _cacheSettingsManager;
    private readonly ICacheHeadersHelper _cacheHeadersHelper;

    private bool? _noStore;
    private CacheSettings _cacheSettings;

    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public string VaryByParam { get; set; }
    public string VaryByCustom { get; set; }
    public string CacheProfile { get; set; }
    public OutputCacheLocation Location { get; set; }

    public bool NoStore {
        get { return _noStore ?? false; }
        set { _noStore = value; }
    }

    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, StringBuilder> ScriptBlocks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, StringBuilder>();

    public DonutOutputCacheAttribute() {
        var keyBuilder = new KeyBuilder();

        _keyGenerator = new KeyGenerator(keyBuilder);
        _donutHoleFiller = new DonutHoleFiller(new EncryptingActionSettingsSerialiser(new ActionSettingsSerialiser(), new Encryptor()));
        _outputCacheManager = new OutputCacheManager(OutputCache.Instance, keyBuilder);
        _cacheSettingsManager = new CacheSettingsManager();
        _cacheHeadersHelper = new CacheHeadersHelper();

        Duration = -1;
        Location = (OutputCacheLocation)(-1);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        _cacheSettings = BuildCacheSettings();

        var cacheKey = _keyGenerator.GenerateKey(filterContext, _cacheSettings);

        if (_cacheSettings.IsServerCachingEnabled) {
            var cachedItem = _outputCacheManager.GetItem(cacheKey);

            if (cachedItem != null) {
                filterContext.Result = new ContentResult {
                    Content = _donutHoleFiller.ReplaceDonutHoleContent(cachedItem.Content, filterContext),
                    ContentType = cachedItem.ContentType
                };

                if (ScriptBlocks.ContainsKey(cacheKey)) {
                    var scriptBuilder = filterContext.HttpContext.Items["ScriptBlockBuilder"] as StringBuilder ?? new StringBuilder();

                    scriptBuilder.Append(ScriptBlocks[cacheKey].ToString());

                    filterContext.HttpContext.Items["ScriptBlockBuilder"] = scriptBuilder;
                }
            }
        }

        if (filterContext.Result == null) {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Items["OutputCacheKey"] = cacheKey;

            var cachingWriter = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            var originalWriter = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Output;

            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Output = cachingWriter;

            filterContext.HttpContext.Items[cacheKey] = new Action<bool>(hasErrors => {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Items.Remove(cacheKey);

                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Output = originalWriter;

                if (!hasErrors) {
                    var cacheItem = new CacheItem {
                        Content = cachingWriter.ToString(),
                        ContentType = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType
                    };

                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(_donutHoleFiller.RemoveDonutHoleWrappers(cacheItem.Content, filterContext));

                    if (_cacheSettings.IsServerCachingEnabled && filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                        _outputCacheManager.AddItem(cacheKey, cacheItem, DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(_cacheSettings.Duration));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext) {
        ExecuteCallback(filterContext, false);

        if (!filterContext.IsChildAction)
            _cacheHeadersHelper.SetCacheHeaders(filterContext.HttpContext.Response, _cacheSettings);
    }

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) {
        if (_cacheSettings != null)
            ExecuteCallback(filterContext, true);
    }

    private void ExecuteCallback(ControllerContext context, bool hasErrors) {
        var cacheKey = _keyGenerator.GenerateKey(context, _cacheSettings);

        var callback = context.HttpContext.Items[cacheKey] as Action<bool>;

        if (callback != null)
            callback.Invoke(hasErrors);
    }

    private CacheSettings BuildCacheSettings() {
        CacheSettings cacheSettings;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CacheProfile)) {
            cacheSettings = new CacheSettings {
                IsCachingEnabled = _cacheSettingsManager.IsCachingEnabledGlobally,
                Duration = Duration,
                VaryByCustom = VaryByCustom,
                VaryByParam = VaryByParam,
                Location = (int)Location == -1 ? OutputCacheLocation.Server : Location,
                NoStore = NoStore
            };
        } else {
            var cacheProfile = _cacheSettingsManager.RetrieveOutputCacheProfile(CacheProfile);

            cacheSettings = new CacheSettings {
                IsCachingEnabled = _cacheSettingsManager.IsCachingEnabledGlobally && cacheProfile.Enabled,
                Duration = Duration == -1 ? cacheProfile.Duration : Duration,
                VaryByCustom = VaryByCustom ?? cacheProfile.VaryByCustom,
                VaryByParam = VaryByParam ?? cacheProfile.VaryByParam,
                Location = (int)Location == -1 ? ((int)cacheProfile.Location == -1 ? OutputCacheLocation.Server : cacheProfile.Location) : Location,
                NoStore = _noStore.HasValue ? _noStore.Value : cacheProfile.NoStore
            };
        }

        if (cacheSettings.Duration == -1) 
            throw new HttpException("The directive or the configuration settings profile must specify the 'duration' attribute.");

        if (cacheSettings.Duration < 0)
            throw new HttpException("The 'duration' attribute must have a value that is greater than or equal to zero.");

        return cacheSettings;
    }
}
```

I also had to modify the Donut Output Cache library to make IExtendedOutputCacheManager and the OutputCacheManager constructor public.

Please note this has been extracted from my application and may require some minor tweaks. You should also place WriteScriptBlocks at the bottom of the page so it is not called until after all child actions are triggered.

Hope this helps.