# Prevent ASP.NET MVC Bundles Loading more than once

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization, bundling-and-minification

is there an inbuilt method of tracking if a bundle has already been loaded? I have several edit views which forexample require jquery and jquery.Validate etc libraries. Which i don't need to reference on the main layout page. 
Since a page could consist of several different conditional libraries ... ideally i would like @scripts.Render to know if i have already referenced a library and prevent its reloading.

Cheers
Tim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think both [Hao Kung](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12572460/712526) and [user108](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12508004/712526) have pieces of your answer.

Hao Kung is addressing the system's ability to know that you have already included a bundle on the page and to avoid adding a duplicate.  This is similar to what [WordPress's enqueue script/style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) does.  MVC does not have this yet.  You would have to build it yourself.

user108 is presenting a possible solution to your problem.  He/she is saying that in your layout you can create an optional "Scripts" section.  Then, in the views that require the jquery validation code you can include it in the "Scripts" section of the layout. This would accomplish most of what you are looking for.  The only place it would not work is if you have multiple view partials on the same page that all require the jquery validation code.

You could implement a solution for this yourself fairly easily.  Here's [a SO post that will get you started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081009/how-to-use-razor-section-multiple-times-in-a-view-partialview-merge-without).

Comment: As you can see, usernames can be changed very freely. I've added links to Hao Kung's and (user108 -> Sender)'s answers, for posterity. Can you verify that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12508004/712526) is the one you were referring to?

Comment: yup... that's the answer - thanks for maintaining the context

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you are asking for something more like asset management, where you can potential register scripts more than once, and to have an API to automatically deduplicate and render the appropriate list.  This is on our todo list, but its not currently part of the API yet.

If this is something that you would like, you can vote for it on our codeplex site:
[This issue](http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/26)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString RequireClientScript(this HtmlHelper helper, string scriptPath)
    {
        var scripts = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["client-script-list"] as Dictionary<string, string> ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();

        if (!scripts.ContainsKey(scriptPath))
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            var scriptTag = new TagBuilder("script");

            scriptTag.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
            scriptTag.Attributes.Add("src", scriptPath);

            sb.AppendLine(scriptTag.ToString());

            scripts.Add(scriptPath, scriptPath);

            helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["client-script-list"] = scripts;

            return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using partial view you needed **reference script libraries**

in page top only add required script add like

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

then body tag bottom add

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

any other page extend **scripts** section like

```
@section scripts{
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

Comment: Sorry User108 im not sure what you are conveying?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.