# Can't define a custom renderer lambda in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to define a custom renderer as a lambda in my MVC view that I can use it in a partial to render the same thing multiple times.  I plan to store it in the view data.  So far I have created this extension method to store the renderer:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
   public static void DefineRenderer<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, string rendererName, Action renderer)
   {
      html.ViewData["_Renderer" + rendererName] = renderer;
   }
}
```

I'm trying to define the renderer in my view, but it isn't working; I assume my syntax is off.  Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?  I just want it to render the test paragraph when called:

```
@Html.DefineRenderer("AnalysisTableHeader", () => {
    <p>test paragraph</p>
@});
```

Comment: What exactly trying to achieve? @helper will not be enough for you?

Comment: What is exactly what you expect your helper to do? Oh and use `ViewBag` instead of `ViewData`, it's a better practice. ;)

Comment: @e.campver Actually I think exactly the opposite.  I steer clear of dynamics whenever I can.  I like my language strongly typed.

Comment: @mariozski I have a partial view which renders a table.  I want the calling code to be able to indicate how to render a "header" row because it needs to be rendered twice.

Comment: @Jez It's still stongly typed, but dynamically. :-) Duck typing and stuff is still impossible.

Comment: @Peit Yeah so you get no Intellisense on it and it seems to cause weird exceptions in the background from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some inspiration from @mariozski's comment, I managed to get the behaviour I wanted to work.  I use a `@helper` as the renderer.  The model I pass to the partial contains the result of the helper render, ie. a `HelperResult`.  So it looks like this:

```
public class AnalysisResponseTableViewModel {
    public HelperResult HeaderTypeRowRenderer { get; set; }
    public List<AnalysisUserResponseViewModel> Responses { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the calling view calls the partial like this:

```
@helper RenderHeaderTypeRow() {
    <tr class="headerTypeRow">
        <td>Header type row</td>
        <td>Goes here</td>
    </tr>
}

@Html.Partial("AnalysisResponseTableContentsPartial",
    new AnalysisResponseTableViewModel {
        Responses = Model.OverallCaseStudyUserResponses,
        HeaderTypeRowRenderer = RenderHeaderTypeRow()
    }
)
```

And finally the partial itself can render the 'header type row' multiple times like this:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.HeaderTypeRowRenderer.ToHtmlString())
@{bool reachedSummaryRows = false;}
@foreach (var response in Model.Responses) {
    if (!reachedSummaryRows && !response.IsPass.HasValue) {
        reachedSummaryRows = true;
        @:@Html.Raw(Model.HeaderTypeRowRenderer.ToHtmlString())
    }

    // other table rows here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DefineRenderer`-method needs to return anything else than void, e.g. `IHtmlString` to call it with the razor `@`-syntax or else you will need to call it like this:

```
@{
    Html.DefineRenderer("AnalysisTableHeader", () => {
        <p>test paragraph</p>
    });
}
```

Edit: Sorry, I've seen that the `renderer` parameter is of type `System.Action`. I think it must be of type `System.Func<dynamic, HelperResult>` and you need to call it

```
@{ Html.DefineRenderer("AnalysisTableHeader", @<text><p>test paragraph</p></text>); }
```

for example. You can then later render it like this: `render(null).ToHtmlString()`. Anyway beware that you might get problems with partial view caching if you do stuff like this in views.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what the partial view caching problems might be?

Comment: Of cause I can: It's about what's currently rendered and what is not. Assuming that you change the signature of the ``DefineRenderer``-method such that it returns ``IHtmlString`` (MvcHtmlString.Empty) and you call ``@Html.DefineRenderer("x", ...)`` in your view. At the moment you use the ``OutputCacheAttribute``, the system saves the resulting Html-markup to the cache (empty string in this case) and won't call the ``DefineRenderer`` method later because it serves the cached result. As soon you try to access the renderer, this will fail because it has never been put into the ViewDataDictionary.

Comment: So what would be the best way of achieving what I want in this case then?

Comment: @Jez This depends on what you are trying to achieve. I think you should always render markup where you need it to avoid problems and difficulties. Can't you use html helpers instead? See also http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx

Comment: I could, but wouldn't I have to have one helper for each different table row I wanted to render?  I think that information should be in the views I'm calling the partial from.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% sure if that's what you need but maybe it'll help.
Define @helper in your partial view and based on value from Model decide which version to render:

Declare enum with header types in your code

```
public enum HeaderTypes
{
    AnalysisTable,
    SomethingElse
}
```

Then in your view

```
@helper RenderHeader(HeaderTypes headerType) {
    switch (headerType)
    {
        case HeaderTypes.AnalysisTable:
            @: <p>your html</p>
            break;
        default: 
            @: <p>default</p>
            break;
    }
}

@RenderHeader(HeaderTypes.None)
@RenderHeader(HeaderTypes.AnalysisTable)
```

Or you can just do switch based on string value or something else.

Comment: Is there a way to pass a helper method into a partial view so my partial could call something like `RenderHeaderRow()` and each view that used the partial would have to define a helper called `RenderHeaderRow`?

Comment: You could probably do something like this in view: @Html.Partial("PartialName", new { renderer = RenderCustom(HeaderTypes.AnalysisTable) }) and in partial: @Model.renderer. Is that sufficient for you? Why not define helper in partial itself? :)

Comment: Because semantically I think it makes sense to define the markup that is different in the parent views in the parent views themselves.  However, your suggestion seems to have worked.  I am developing it now and will probably post an answer with your solution, refined.