# where to add jQueryUI scripts in MVC page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm using an EditorTemplates folder, and the following DateTime.cshtml to add the date picker (jQuery UI) to all Datetime fields:

```
@model Nullable<System.DateTime>
@if ( Model.HasValue ) {
@Html.TextBox( "" , String.Format( "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}" , Model.Value ) , new  {     @class = "textbox" , @style = "width:400px;" } )
}
else {
@Html.TextBox( "" , String.Format( "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}" , DateTime.Now ) , new {     @class = "textbox" , @style = "width:400px;" } )
}

@{
string name = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
string id = name.Replace( ".", "_" );
}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("adding date picker");
    $("#@id").datepicker
        ({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            showStatus: true,
            showWeeks: true,
            highlightWeek: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            showAnim: "scale",
            showOptions: {
                origin: ["top", "left"]
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

However, if I add the jQuery Scripts etc to the bottom of the page, as is suggested is best practice now - the above code, appears inline - above the jQuery scripts - and therefore doesn't run:

Main CSHTML Razor view:

```
 @RenderBody()   
        <hr>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; Company @System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy")</p>
        </footer> 
    </div>
     @Scripts.Render("~/js")
     @Scripts.Render("~/jqueryui")
     @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Should I bypass the best practice and add the jQuery scripts to the top of the page - or is there a simpler way of making this work, while still following best practice?

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: The @Scripts.Render should be within the head tag, no?

Comment: Have you tried to use window.onload = function{...}; instead of document.ready  ?  Or go with Kenneth's answer which seems more accurate in your case.

Comment: @MelanciaUK: The scripts should not go in the head-tag, this will slow down the page render.

Comment: @roasted: if he uses window.onload then his script will be executed later than strictly necessary

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081009/how-to-use-razor-section-multiple-times-in-a-view-partialview-merge-without

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have any scripts in your views or partials. Scripts should be placed where they belong - in separate javascript files.

So you could have a javascript file that enables datepickers, for example `~/scripts/myscript.js`:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    showStatus: true,
    showWeeks: true,
    highlightWeek: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    showAnim: "scale",
    showOptions: {
        origin: ["top", "left"]
    }
});
```

As you can see I have used a class selector here: `$('.datepicker')` in order to attach the datepicker plugin to all input fields that have `class="datepicker"`.

And now all that's left is to override the Scripts custom section in your view (not in partials or templates):

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/myscript.js"></script>
}
```

Now your template will contain only what templates should contain - markup:

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox(
    "", 
    string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}", Model ?? DateTime.Now), 
    new { 
        @class = "textbox datepicker", 
        @style = "width:400px;" 
    } 
)
```

You might also notice the simplification of the code.

And now since you followed best practices to have all your scripts in separate files you could even have a bundle for them:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/datepickers")
}
```

or simply include it in some of the bundles in your Layout so that it gets minified and cached with them and available to all pages.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit more?

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's problem, he'd still need to reference the script from his partial view, since he only wants to include it when the partial view is loaded

Comment: No, he doesn't need to reference any script from a partial view. Scripts should be referenced only from main views or inside the Layout. @Floremin, what additional elaboration would you like me to do?

Comment: I think you have elaborated with your last update. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you everyone - I have added the script to a JS, and to the bundling - and also simplified the markup.  As always, I'm grateful for the assistance.  Mark

Answer (score 2):

You should put it in the section:

```
@section Scripts { 

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("adding date picker");
    $("#@id").datepicker
        ({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            showStatus: true,
            showWeeks: true,
            highlightWeek: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            showAnim: "scale",
            showOptions: {
                origin: ["top", "left"]
            }
        });
});
</script>
}
```

This way your script will be added below the jQuery declaration

Comment: Where would the `@id` come from? Don't forget that you cannot have sections in partials or templates.